# How to insert the group_id of a user to 'auth_user_groups' table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to insert the `group_id` of a user(`user` in `auth_user` table) to `auth_user_groups` table.  How can we achieve this?

To insert into `auth_user` table we can do

```
details = User(username = "somename",password = "somepassword", email = "email",
first_name =  "firstname",
last_name =  "lastname",
is_staff = 0,
is_active = 1,
is_superuser = 0                                
)
details.save()
```

Is there any method like

```
save = auth_user_groups(user_id=1,group_id = 5)
```

this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
group = Group.objects.get(id=5)

user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: what if I don't want to query group table to get group instance (basically i don't want to run your 2nd line of code). I want to pass specific group_id (in your 3rd line of code) to the auth_user_group table. do you think it is possible?